# What decision should I take regarding a team of front-end developers which delivers unstable releases

Tags: project-team, project-management-style, clients, deadline, deliverables

I own a front-end development team who's task is to develop a single page web application based on Angular technology stack.

Product is currently in beta stage and never been public, only client team and the team of testers have access to this. The requirements are very much agile and I'm keeping hard to keep everything persistent during sprints and day to day work.

However the work developers are delivering tend to be more error prone and very fragile. They tend to do same mistake over and over however the internal QA team sits as a boundary before the client.
Due to the app's fragile nature,even QA team can't get caught up all the bugs.

Due to this reason, all the work is now behind, My deliveries are getting late, deadline missing is now a common thing. Client frustration is also a common now. I'm running out of options. 
What an experienced PM would do in this moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Product is currently in beta stage and never been public, only client
>   team and the team of testers have access to this.

How often is the client checking in?  Do you have regular reviews?   You want the feedback loop short and *actionable*.

> The requirements are very much agile and I'm keeping hard to keep everything persistent during sprints and day to day work.

This could be some red flags that you are having to work very hard.  The team should be improving.   Are you running regular retrospectives?  If not, then you should start and ensure that the meetings are focused.

> However the work developers are delivering tend to be more error prone and very fragile.

This could be one of several things or a combination of things. Let's unpack it.

- Are the team highly skilled?
- Are they learning new frameworks and technologies?  If so, then they need time to absorb the new information and improve
- Are they practising *drive-by coding* which is where you care more about the tickets being marked as done and the plan being adhered to rather than letting them have the time and space to craft quality code?

> They tend to do same mistake over and over however the internal QA team sits as a boundary before the client.

A retrospective should have flagged this.  It might be time to *stop the production line* to ensure that all of the Developers are committed to improving, both themselves and the codebase.

How does the code enter the code-base?  Does it go through a code-review?  Do you practise pair programming?  Do you have GIT gatekeepers?  Is there an automated service for flagging errors?

> Due to the app's fragile nature,even QA team can't get caught up all the bugs.

Why do you have a separate QA team?  What sort of activities do they conduct?  How do you define a bug?  It this a lack of requirement clarity?  Are you using user stories?  Do they have clear acceptance criteria?

> Due to this reason, all the work is now behind, My deliveries are getting late, deadline missing is now a common thing. Client frustration is also a common now. I'm running out of options. What an experienced PM would do in this moment?

The truth is, this does not sound very Agile.  It sounds like some waterfall activities with some Agile patterns bolted on over the top.  Water-Scrum-Fall.

Unfortunately, without greater access to your team, you technologies and your environment, it is very difficult to provide you with constructive advice.

I will simply say what a previous coach said to me once.

***Cut the bullshit***

If you implement Agile patterns, then implement them.  Pick a framework; I advise Scrum.  Implement it and see where the gaps lie.

At present the range of issues could be anything from inexperienced developers to time-pressure to unclear requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, lot more I've learned from this. Yes as you told, we are trying to blend the agile with already familiar waterfall system.
As you pointed out now it's kind of clear where the problem lies. 
We have very long feedback period from client, devs aren't skill full, they don't have time to absorb the value, retrospective meetings were long gone, testers should fit inside the team however they work as a separate entity. We don't have automated code testing tools. I'm gonna accept this answer and try to implement what is missing on my agile team.